# Can Git run hooks with source instead of as an executable?

Tags: git

I want to use Git to manage the files in a directory on my cheap web hosting provider. The provider gives me SSH access and has Git installed, but doesn't allow me to add executable hooks.

Specifically, I want to create a `post-receive` hook that checks the recent push out on the server, allowing me to commit changes locally and then push them to the web hosting provider.

I found an example for doing this with [GoDaddy](https://adamboother.com/blog/install-git-on-a-godaddy-shared-hosting-account/), but my provider has limited the SSH shell. After tinkering a bit, I can see that I am allowed to source scripts, but not execute them.

```sh
chmod +x .git/hooks/post-receive

. .git/hooks/post-receive
# OK

./.git/hooks/post-receive
# bash: ./.git/hooks/post-receive: Permission denied
```

My question is this: can I make Git run hooks with `source` instead of directly executing them?